# Email Notification with custom rules?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

I am using Microsoft Outlook on Windows7. To organize my mails I have created rules to automatically send the email to a subfolder in the Inbox when mails are there from certain people. But I don't get any notification for these mails.

How to enable notification for the mails moved into subfolder because of Rules?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this has been relly giving me problems for a while now. I fixed it by adding another rule before the moving one which notifies me

```
From=someone@someemail.com notify
From=someone@someemail.com move to subfolder
```

This however is only fixing the symptom of the error but not a fix on the error itself. Maybe this has been fixed in Outlook 2010 ? I'm using 2007.

Comment: I am too on Outlook 2007 but seems to be quiet a basic requirement and notification should have worked with subfolders inside inbox.

Comment: At least in modern versions of Outlook one can combine them into one rule.